# Change the focus in EXCEL cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

What do I need to change so when I click for example A5 the focus should be changed to B3, So when I click B5 the focus should go to C3 and so forth....

So my code right now is:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Not Application.Intersect(Range("A5:D5"), Target) Is Nothing Then
    Range("A3").Select
  End If
End Sub
```

So when I select a row 5 from A to D the point is moved to A3 ..instead of A3 I would like to change to the next column on the row 3.

Thank you

Comment: Hmm. Are you sure you want to do this? If clicking a cell transfers the focus somewhere else you can never edit the original cells contents ...

Comment: I don't want to edit this cell at all so this is what I need to do

Comment: If you're trying to protect the contents of the cell by doing this, note that you can't stop people from editing the file through other means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Not Application.Intersect(Range("A5:D5"), Target) Is Nothing Then
  Application.EnableEvents = False
      Target.Offset(-2, 1).Select
   Application.EnableEvents = True
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Works perfect mate, Thanks. Do you have any idea would that work in excel 2003

Comment: @ГеоргиДаскалов  Should work in any version of **Excel** that supports *VBA*